# fseek would not return the expected location

Tags: c, pointers, memory, file-handling

I have a function where I am trying to reach the last index of the file contents. When i use descriptors and lseek combination as given below, things work normally:

```
offset = lseek(infd, 0, SEEK_END);
```

results in offset: 39 (which byte size of the file)

infd is 3

```
offset = fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
```

results in offset 0

file1 is pointing to 0x00007fff8897e320

Why is the offset resulting in 0 when I try to use a file pointer to the same?

**Note:** offset is of type off_t

Comment: Did you open the file in text mode? SEEK_END is not valid for text files.

Comment: I am using "rb" mode. @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: _file1 is pointing to 0x00007fff8897e320_: this is irrelevant. The content of a file pointer or the thing it points to is opaque, you shouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `fseek`, if you read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) you can find:

> Return value
>
> ​0​ upon success, nonzero value otherwise.

On the other hand, `lseek` [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) reads:

> Return value
>
> Upon successful completion, lseek() returns the resulting offset
> location as measured in bytes from the beginning of the file.

Hope this clears thing up, and next time I really advise you to read the reference and check for return value section!

Comment: I see. I don't fully follow how I can use fseek to set the file position indicator to the end then.

Comment: @ankitrana_: You set it just fine. But if you want to read back the resulting position you need `ftell` or `ftello` (note: prefer `ftello` and likewise `fseeko` on POSIX systems since plain `ftell` can't necessarily handle large files) after the successful seek.